# 4-bit Self-correcting Johnson Counter on D flip-flops

Tags: digital-logic, counter

I had a task assigned by my teacher to implement self correcting Johnson Counter. The task goes this way:

> Design a self-adjusted 4 bit Johnson counter. Counter must be implemented on d flip flops and perform self adjusting only on 1st bit. Design should preferably be made with use of Johnson's code.

Frankly, I have no idea how to tackle this task. I made all but this one, I read the other questions/answers here but I'm still not sure.

Could you please at least give me a hint how to do this task?

Comment: What **do** you know? Do you what an ideal Johnson counter i? Do you know the difference between legal and illegal states? How would you detect an illegal state? How would you adjust a bit?

Comment: I know that Johnson counter is one of ring counters and 4-bit one basically has 8 legal and 8 illegal states from what I can say. I think I could detect the illegal state through putting out outputs from flip-flops through and gates to see if the combination of outputs is legal or not. I don't know however what to do if I actually find that illegal state, and what 'adjusting only on first bit' means.

Comment: I suspect that only adjusting the first bit means only applying the correction at the first flip-flop,

Comment: @Slajni OK then, edit this information into your question, so that we have some idea of where to pitch the level of the answer, and that we also have some sense that your are doing some thinking for yourself. You might like to draw a schematic for an ideal 4 bit 8 state counter (the pencil/diode/resistor/capacitor button on the edit bar). Think about the word 'adjust', especially in the context of logic, which has only 0 and 1 states. In an ideal counter, you'd normally send a bit unaltered to the next flop. Now 'adjusting' that bit could mean only ??? what ???

Comment: Right, give me some time, I will try to sketch what I can.

Comment: I'll observe that a restriction in the question, only adjust the first bit, means that some illegal states **cannot** be corrected in one clock cycle. Therefore the question is explicitly allowing time to correct the error over several clock cycles.

Comment: @Slajni For ideas and detailed discussion, you might examine US patent: [US4646332A](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/63/46/96/e86652e4b418f1/US4646332.pdf). (It's expired.)

Comment: Ok, so at first, I would like to know if following k-map for 1st flip flop would provide self-adjusting features and if grouping is made properly 
https://gifyu.com/image/Eihj

Comment: @Slajni  drawing k-maps is hard work, and incomprehensible unless you've labelled your diagram, and I don't see a diagram yet. Hint, note that some of the illegal states have 010 next to each other, and none of the legal states do. What do you make of that?

Comment: The first thing I thought of is that I just have to see if there are situations where 'every second flip flop' outputs 1. I mean that in case of this counter 1's should be never separated by zeros. But how do I make it 'correcting only at first bit'?

Comment: @Slajni Hmmmm, it feels like you're over-thinking this. There are two cycles, a valid cycle, and an illegal cycle. You know how to find the illegal cycle, at least one of its states will have 101 in it (1's separated by a zero). You stay in the illegal cycle by obeying all the Qn->Dn+1 shift polarities. You can flip from the illegal cycle to the valid one by inverting any Q->D transfer, if you pick the Q0->D1 transfer then it's 'only at the first bit'. When do you do it? For one cycle if you detect a 010 in a suitable 3 adjacent Qs. It's easier to discuss with a labelled schematic.

Comment: Okay then. I made something like that: https://gifyu.com/image/EjWI
Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

A correctly-operating 4-bit Johnson counter loops through 8 legal states. But any collection of four FFs has a total of 2<sup>4</sup> = 16 possible states. Therefore, there are also 8 "illegal" states.

Since you know the circuit for a Johnson counter, you can draw the complete state transition diagram (or table) for all 16 states. The illegal states will form one or more loops, too. Some of the illegal states can be converted to legal states by flipping only the first bit.

Find them, and implement the logic to do this. Then verify that ALL of the illegal states eventually get to a legal state.